# Apache Kafka Producer 'request.timeout.ms' property

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I want to understanding the meaning of request.timeout.ms that is used in
producer. As per the doc this property is used to expire records that have
been waiting for response from server for more than `request.timeout.ms`
which also means the records have been sitting in for more
than request.timeout.ms.I discovered that `request.timeout.ms` is used for
another purpose: to expire records that sit in batch.size for more than
`request.timeout.ms`.Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any batches that have been sitting in RecordAccumulator for more than the configured request.timeout.ms due to metadata being unavailable will be thought of expired, and sender metric will record such batches for monitoring.